# Heap profiler's reports vs task manager's reports: who to believe?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a Chrome extension that appears to have a memory leak: Chrome's task manager reports a gradually increasing memory footprint. But when I use the dev tools profiler to take heap snapshots and compare them, I see net negative size deltas. So, why don't these two tools agree?

Is Task Manager measuring something in addition to or different from heap? I see mentions of "javascript heap" vs "native memory" -- how do these affect what these tools report? And what is meant by native memory in this context?

This is basically the same question as in [Interpretation of memory usage in chrome task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756853/interpretation-of-memory-usage-in-chrome-task-manager) and [Chrome Heap Snapshot - Why it doesn't show all the memory allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318109/chrome-heap-snapshot-why-it-doesnt-show-all-the-memory-allocated), but neither of these got a conclusive answer. So I'm hoping the third try is a charm, and someone can lay it all out.

*Additional information*: OK, I see you can add more columns to Task Manager, including "javascript memory." (Also: "goats teleported.") Presumably that column should correlate pretty closely with what I see in the Heap Profiler. And indeed it climbs up a little and then goes down, and is generally acting reassuringly non-leaky. So what is the Task Manager memory column?  The javascript and the DOM and the HTML and the CSS and ... what else?